# How to get the variance of a VAR(1) model in statsmodels?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I estimate a VAR(1) model in statsmodels (the sample code is from [statsmodels user guide](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/vector_ar.html)).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR
from statsmodels.tsa.base.datetools import dates_from_str

# prepare the data
mdata = sm.datasets.macrodata.load_pandas().data
dates = mdata[['year', 'quarter']].astype(int).astype(str)
quarterly = dates["year"] + "Q" + dates["quarter"]
quarterly = dates_from_str(quarterly)
mdata = mdata[['realgdp','realcons','realinv']]
mdata.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(quarterly)
data = np.log(mdata).diff().dropna()

# make a VAR model
model = VAR(data)
results = model.fit(1)
```

I want to compute the variance of the VAR model (click [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251067/unconditional-mean-and-variance-of-a-stationary-var1-model) for an explanation). Is there an attribute or property of the `VARResults` object that can give the variance directly?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer.

```
results.acf(0)
```

The `acf()` method of the `VARResults` object computes theoretical autocovariance function of the VAR model.